# .htaccess - Redirect domain2.com to domain1.com/folder without changing the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have two domainnames. Let's say domain1.com and domain2.com.
My main website is running on domain1.com.
I want to run a blog on domain1.com/blog but I want to use domain2.com as the url for this blog.

I currently have this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain1.com/blog [P]
```

This works but the url changes to domain2.com/blog when I enter domain2.com  and I just want domain2.com without /blog.

I've been searching for over an hour and I can't find the right solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain1.com/blog/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and use this in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1
```

This will take `domain2.com/blog` and make the resulting URL show `domain2.com` but still load the content in the `/blog` folder.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.